# USB-C keyboard problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I have a Delux T9X keyboard which has a USB-C port. I tried to connect it to my Macbook Pro with a type-c/type-c cable, but it doesn't works. Then I tried to connect it with a type-c/type-a cable through an adapter and it works well. I tried other type-c/type-c cables which I have with same results. What I do wrong?

Comment: Most likely it requires a USB2.x cable and will not work with anything else (and I mean ANYTHING else!). I have the same issue with a Drop ALT keyboard and am stuck using an adapter and a USBA to USBC adapter.

Comment: @TomGewecke it's named as Delux T9X.

Comment: @DaveNelson I'v read about something like this. Sounds like you're right.